# Convert nested list into dict with key and multiple list values if exist

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a nested list as below. Since list is very huge and to reduce search time, thought would be better to convert as dict.

With innerlist[index] to be key and rest to be values. Incase key is occuring twice need to add list of values in dict.

List

```
[
 ['001', 'xxxx', 'xxxx'], 
 ['002', '1', 'H', '0', 'H'], 
 ['002', '1', 'Z', '0', 'H']
]
```

Need Dict as follows

```
   {
        '001': ['xxxx', 'xxxx'],
        '002': [
                ['1', 'H','0', 'H'],
                ['1', 'Z','0', 'H']
        ],
    }
```

I did it with following code, still seems not an optimum way for a huge list. Also for non duplicated item, I get nested list with 1 item. '001': [['xxxx', 'xxxx']],
Let me know if a better way is possible.

```
data_dict = dict()
for data in bytes_data:
    if data[0] in data_dict:
        data_dict[data[0]].append(data[1:])
    else:
        data_dict[data[0]] = [data[1:]]
```

Comment: *Why* do you think this is not optimal? what other way to you think is possible to achieve what you want? How big is a "huge" list? did you time your code?

Comment: It is running on a scheduled job and runs every 5 minutes to read remote file. The list number is 10k+ and screen is loading for a couple of sec for clients.

Comment: do you know which parts take the more time... (downloading?) and loading the remote file into memory as a list, or turning the list into a dict as above?

Comment: @KellyBundy yes, it gave me like [[my_list]]. Still I could access it going inner. That's why wanted a better solution.

Comment: @Anentropic the other two process I cannot control it, I was searching if there is any possibility to reduce here.

Comment: if you don't need the intermediate list form for anything else it'd also be more efficient if you output the dict directly when reading the file (avoid iterating over the 10k+ lines twice)

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a recent Python version (3.5+ I think) you can do this more concisely like:

```py
data = [
  ['001', 'xxxx', 'xxxx'],
  ['002', '1', 'H', '0', 'H'],
  ['002', '1', 'Z', '0', 'H']
]

data_dict = {}

for key, *vals in data:
    data_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(vals)
```

But I suggest benchmarking it, the code you have may be more efficient, especially if many of the keys do not have repeat entries in the src list.